# Correct way to temporarily enable and disable function wrapping in cmocka?

Tags: c, unit-testing, cmockery, cmocka

I am using the [cmocka](http://www.cmocka.org) library to test some embedded c code. According to the documentation I use the `__wrap_` prefix to mock functions so I can isolate my unit tests. However once I do that all calls to the function forever go to the wrapped function. How do I re-enable the real function in certain circumstances so I can test it or allow other functions to use it? It seems to me the only way is to use a global field as a switch to call the real function like so:

```
int __wrap_my_function(void) {
    if (g_disable_wrap_my_function) {
        return __real_my_function();
    }

    // ... do mock stuff
}
```

Is that the correct way to go about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up doing exactly what I suggested in my question. I used a global variable that I check in the wrapped function to enable and disable the mocking at runtime.

Comment: This is not a nice solution. You should better do what @asn has written: 'compile without the -wrap command line option'

Comment: @eDeviser That obviously won't work. What could be done is to split the tests into two files. One set of tests that is run with the mock, using the --wrap flag and one that uses the real function. You can even do this to have different mocks for different functions under tests, but your way is the simplest. If you don't need the mock value you could even use it as the control variable. It's a bit of a hack, but so is Cmocka.

Answer (score 4):

You simply compile without the -wrap command line option.

Or you use defines:

```
#include <cmocka.h>
#ifdef UNIT_TESTING
#define strdup test_strdup
#endif
```

Add the mock function test_strdup. You can now use this function to test.

Comment: I don't understand your answer, why would I use #define to mock a function like strdup? The whole point of cmocka is that it allows me to mock functions in conjunction with the `--wrap` gcc option. I want to know how using cmocka I could mock strdup for one unit test and not mock it for a different unit test.